# How to deploy Node.js in cloud for high availability using multi-core, reverse-proxy, and SSL

Tags: deployment, node.js

I have posted this to ServerFault, but the Node.js community seems tiny there, so I'm hoping this bring more exposure.

I have a Node.js (0.4.9) application and am researching how to best deploy and maintain it. I want to run it in the cloud (EC2 or RackSpace) with high availability. The app should run on HTTPS. I'll worry about East/West/EU full-failover later.

I have done a lot of reading about keep-alive (Upstart, Forever), multi-core utilities (Fugue, multi-node, Cluster), and proxy/load balancers (node-http-proxy, nginx, Varnish, and Pound). However, I am unsure how to combine the various utilities available to me.

I have this setup in mind and need to iron out some questions and get feedback.

1. **Cluster** is the most actively developed and seemingly popular multi-core utility for Node.js, so use that to run 1 node "cluster" per app server on non-privileged port (say 3000). **Q1:** Should **Forever** be used to keep the cluster alive or is that just redundant?
2. Use 1 **nginx** per app server running on port 80, simply reverse proxying to node on port 3000. **Q2:** Would **node-http-proxy** be more suitable for this task even though it doesn't gzip or server static files quickly?
3. Have minimum 2x servers as described above, with an independent server acting as a load balancer across these boxes. Use **Pound** listening 443 to terminate HTTPS and pass HTTP to **Varnish** which would round robin load balance across the IPs of servers above. **Q3:** Should **nginx** be used to do both instead? **Q4:** Should AWS or RackSpace load balancer be considered instead (the latter doesn't terminate HTTPS)

**General Questions:**

1. Do you see a need for (2) above at all?
2. Where is the best place to terminate HTTPS?
3. If **WebSockets** are needed in the future, what nginx substitutions would you make?

I'd really like to hear how people are setting up current production environments and which combination of tools they prefer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Note that Cluster etc. do not provide multi-threading, they simply provide usage of multiple cores through multiple processes. This is entirely different. Note also that Cluster will not provide high availability if your master goes down. The childs will suicide and the master will not respawn. Maybe you can use something like Forever to restart the master. Also, note that Nginx is incapable of routing websocket connections. Finally, "an independent server acting as a load balancer across these boxes": what if this server goes down?

Comment: @Tom, all excellent points. I will update the question to note multi-core usage, not multi-threading, but the former is what I meant. I'd use Monit on each server to watch Cluster's PID and restart it if necessary. I understand nginx's current WS/WSS limitation but don't need that yet. I'd use Monit on the load balancer too, but don't as of yet have a good solution for that single point of failure, short of multiple availability zones (duplicates of this entire setup).

Comment: @ChrisF go talk to the nodejitsu guys in #nodejitsu on freenode. If you want to know about node architecture that's the place to be.

Comment: @Chris F, I have never implemented this, but I am personally considering: 1. setup round robin DNS (each server/node is appointed randomly) 2. each server has its own instance of node-http-proxy or nginx 3. each server uses redis to know about the load of other servers 4. each server redirects incoming requests if there is a more appropriate server for this request

Comment: If you're having trouble getting answers on stackexchange, try ask on the  google group: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs or on irc.freenode.net #Node.js

Comment: @secoif Thanks, seems like that's the case.

Comment: Round Robin DNS is kinda lame in 2011, if a node fails, fixing it takes human intervention, unless you have a cunning DNS server.  The whole rest of the sentence just seems like mechanisms to mitigate this when you could just use load balancing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's been several months since I asked this question and not a lot of answer flow. Both Samyak Bhuta and nponeccop had good suggestions, but I wanted to discuss the answers I've found to my questions.

Here is what I've settled on at this point for a production system, but further improvements are always being made. I hope it helps anyone in a similar scenario.

1. Use Cluster to spawn as many child processes as you desire to handle incoming requests on multi-core virtual or physical machines. This binds to a single port and makes maintenance easier. My rule of thumb is n - 1 Cluster workers. You don't need Forever on this, as Cluster respawns worker processes that die. To have resiliency even at the Cluster parent level, ensure that you use an Upstart script (or equivalent) to daemonize the Node.js application, and use Monit (or equivalent) to watch the PID of the Cluster parent and respawn it if it dies. You can try using the respawn feature of Upstart, but I prefer having Monit watching things, so rather than split responsibilities, I find it's best to let Monit handle the respawn as well.
2. Use 1 nginx per app server running on port 80, simply reverse proxying to your Cluster on whatever port you bound to in (1). node-http-proxy can be used, but nginx is more mature, more featureful, and faster at serving static files. Run nginx lean (don't log, don't gzip tiny files) to minimize it's overhead.
3. Have minimum 2x servers as described above in a minimum of 2 availability zones, and if in AWS, use an ELB that terminates HTTPS/SSL on port 443 and communicates on HTTP port 80 to the node.js app servers. ELBs are simple and, if you desire, make it somewhat easier to auto-scale. You could run multiple nginx either sharing an IP or round-robin balanced themselves by your DNS provider, but I found this overkill for now. At that point, you'd remove the nginx instance on each app server.

I have not needed WebSockets so nginx continues to be suitable and I'll revisit this issue when WebSockets come into the picture.

Feedback is welcome.

Comment: why did you use nginx? to serve static content or as a router to different app servers? If only to serve static content then why not s3?

Comment: I'm really curious to know if you considered using the tool PM2 and strong-loops own 'slc' toolset mainly the 'scl deploy' and 'scl pm'

Answer (score 2):

You should not bother serving static files quickly. If your load is small - node static file servers will do. If your load is big - it's better to use a CDN (Akamai, Limelight, CoralCDN).

Instead of forever you can use monit.

Instead of nginx you can use HAProxy. It is known to work well with websockets. Consider also proxying flash sockets as they are a good workaround until websocket support is ubiquitous (see socket.io).

HAProxy has some support for HTTPS load balancing, but not termination. You can try to use stunnel for HTTPS termination, but I think it's too slow.

Round-robin load (or other statistical) balancing works pretty well in practice, so there's no need to know about other servers' load in most cases.

Consider also using ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ for communications between nodes.

Comment: Curious, what advantage would Zero/RabbitMQ have over just using native nodeJS sockets for inter-node communication?

Comment: @XHR: Using an MQ can provide more sophisticated communication between multiple nodes, including broadcast messages and messages into a job queue that can be serviced by exactly one of the next available nodes. Think of MQ as self-organizing and self-healing sockets.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent thread! Thanks to everyone that contributed useful information.

I've been dealing with the same issues the past few months setting up the infrastructure for our startup.

As people mentioned previously, we wanted a Node environment with multi-core support + web sockets + vhosts

We ended up creating a hybrid between the native cluster module and http-proxy and called it **Drone** - of course it's open sourced:

https://github.com/makesites/drone

We also released it as an AMI with Monit and Nginx

https://aws.amazon.com/amis/drone-server

I found this thread researching how to add SSL support to Drone - tnx for recommending ELB but I wouldn't rely on a proprietary solution for something so crucial.

Instead I extended the default proxy to handle all the SSL requests. The configuration is minimal while the SSL requests are converted to plain http - but I guess that's preferable when you're passing traffic between ports...

Feel free to look into it and let me know if it fits your needs. All feedback welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen AWS load balancer to load balance and termination + http-node-proxy for reverse proxy, if you want to run multiple service per box + cluster.js for mulicore support and process level failover doing extremely well.

forever.js on cluster.js could be good option for extreme care you want to take in terms of failover but that's hardly needed.